# $watch on checkbox not working

Tags: angularjs, checkbox, watch

I am using [angular-bootstrap-checkbox](https://github.com/sebastianha/angular-bootstrap-checkbox) like below:

**HTML**

```
<checkbox class="checkbox" ng-model="manualPosition"></checkbox>
```

I want to watch the changes for the checkbox values.

**JS**

```
$scope.$watch('manualPosition', function(manualPosition) {
    console.log('here');
});
```

It doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 3):

You have to add a watch for whatever the $scope variable

```
$scope.$watch('manualPosition', function (checkboxVal) {
    console.log(checkboxVal);
});
```

And your html should be like this,

```
<input type="checkbox"  ng-model="manualPosition"> CLICK</input>
```

[**DEMO**](https://plnkr.co/edit/sqZj1BjaZYG0UDtkHkj8?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I am sorry for the typo. I have done the same. but not working for me.

Comment: Thanks again. This way it works for me. Since in my project we are already using `angular-bootstrap-checkbox`, I want the `$watch` to work on that.